# Get folder with most recent date

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have task where i have to find most recent added folder (which are named by dates). The problem is that when i fetch dir with all folders with date my array contains full path of folder not only date folder. Let mi give you and example of my code and sample out put...

This is my code

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob(__DIR__ . '/../../../var/Html/*'), 'is_dir');
var_dump($dirs);
$mostRecent= 0;
foreach($dirs as $date){
    $curDate = strtotime($date);
    if ($curDate > $mostRecent) {
        $mostRecent = $curDate;
    }
}
var_dump($mostRecent);
die();
```

And this is the output i get

```
D:\wamp64\www\mypage\public_html\rest>php index.php cli/pars parseFiles
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(111) "D:\wamp64\www\mypage\public_html\rest\application\controllers\cli/../../../var/Html/2017-07-15"
  [1]=>
  string(111) "D:\wamp64\www\mypage\public_html\rest\application\controllers\cli/../../../var/Html/2017-07-16"
}
int(0)
```

So i believe that the problem is because var $dirs contains full path of my dirs instead only date folder name. How can i overcome my problem? Thank you

Comment: You can get the directories you are looking for using `basename()`.

Comment: And if you put these results in an array, you can easily sort the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) — Returns trailing name component of path.

In your case it will look like:

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob(__DIR__ . '/../../../var/Html/*'), 'is_dir');

foreach($dirs as $dir) {
    var_dump(basename($dir));
}
```

Output:

```
string(10) "2017-07-15"
string(10) "2017-07-16"
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your code is as below. `basename` will give you the folder name from full path string.

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob(__DIR__ . '/../../../var/Html/*'), 'is_dir');
var_dump($dirs);
$mostRecent= 0;
foreach($dirs as $date){
    $curDate = strtotime(basename($date));
    if ($curDate > $mostRecent) {
        $mostRecent = $curDate;
    }
}
var_dump($mostRecent);
die();
```